# Create Cluster with New-Cluster in workflow and inlinescript failed

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing, powershell-workflow

When I try to install a cluster remotely from an other host with PowerShell in a workflow and an inlinescript like this:

```psh
workflow CreateClusterCL1 {
  $password = "xxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
  $username = "xxxx"
  $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
  inlinescript {
    New-Cluster -Name xxx-CL1 -StaticAddress xxx -Node xxx-01, xxx-02, xxx-03, xxx-04 -NoStorage -Force
  } -PSComputerName xxx-01.xx.loc -PSCredential $credential 
}
```

I receive this error:

```
CategoryInfo          : **PermissionDenied**: (:) [New-Cluster], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : **UnauthorizedAccess,**Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.NewClusterCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [xxxx-01.xxxx]
New-Cluster : There was an error adding node 'xxx-03' to the cluster
    You do not have administrative privileges on the server 'xxx-03.xxx.LOC'.
    Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
At CreateClusterCL1:8 char:8
```

Any Idea?

Comment: I wonder if this is a similar issue to what was seen in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28114640/3829407) to another workflow question. By default, each command in a workflow is executed with no PowerShell state sharing. I think `$credential` is null when executed.

Comment: @Matt According to [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/privatecloud/archive/2013/08/27/automation-service-management-automation-tip-trick-leveraging-inlinescript-and-using-variable-with-powershell-workflow.aspx) it should work, although I can't test it here. The eventlogs on xxx-03 should provide more information, though.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I should think that the variables need to be initialized inside the inline script as well.... could be wrong though. Haven't delved into workflows that much.

Comment: the output of creatial is filled : PSComputerName        : SSDI3-01.de1.loc
PSSourceJobInstanceId : 624fc331-3bb4-4d89-b778-cf7cad20abee
UserName              : de1\administrator
Password              : System.Security.SecureString  --> perhaps run as computer account...but how ?